# JSON - safely add a variable

Tags: c#, json

How do I safely add a variable to JSON data with C#? For instance I might have `[{"data": "data"}, {"data": "data"}]` or I might have `{"data": "data"}`. How do I add a new variable `"newdata": "newdata"` to the structure?

Comment: How are you currently handling the JSON? Any particular API? Or just a `string`? Or what?

Comment: @Marc, just `string`, as I don't want to deserialize it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the availability of the .Net 3.5SP1 framework, have a look at the JSONReaderWriterFactory class. It makes a XmlDictionaryReader/Writer for use with JSON.

You can use a reader/writer combination to read what's there, write what was there and add your own entries.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Won't be able to test it until Monday, but I think you are on the right track here.